# ng-show doesn't catch the updated value of $invalid from the directive, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest

The problem is: when I focus on a field an blur it, it shows me the error msg and border color around the input field, then I focus it again and I write 0 and blur it, it still shows me the input red border but not the error msg.

The field should contain a value greater than 1.00, but when I load the page the default value it's 0.00, but if you touch/focus the field when blur it, the error should came up.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 a24sm-5">
                        <input class="form-control" gh-amount-field  name="singleLimit" id="singleLimit" ng-model="crCtrl.form.limits.single.val" ng-blur="crCtrl.form.limits.single.errFn()" tabindex="7" />
                        <span class="visible-xs msg-container msg-single">
                                <span class="gh-error" ng-show="cardRules.singleLimit.$invalid">{{crCtrl.form.requiredMsg}}</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

The directive it's:

```
directive("ghAmountField", function(){
    return{
        require:    "^form",
        link:   function(s, el, attrs, formCtrl){
                    var initialAmount;

                    el.on("blur", function(){
                        var min = attrs.hasOwnProperty("amountMin") ? parseFloat(attrs.amountMin) : false;
                        var max = attrs.hasOwnProperty("amountMax") ? parseFloat(attrs.amountMax) : false;
                        var req = attrs.hasOwnProperty("required");

                        var amount = $(this).val().length > 0 ? $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "") : initialAmount.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");

                        if( amount.length>0) {
                            amount = parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
                            $(this).val("£"+amount);
                        }
                        else{
                            $(this).val("£"+initialAmount);
                            amount = initialAmount;
                        }

                        formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid = false;

                        if(!req && amount<1){//after first changing you cannot put zero but at least 1.00
                            $(this).val("£"+initialAmount);
                            amount = initialAmount;
                            formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid = initialAmount<1 ? true : false;
                        }

                        console.log(amount, initialAmount);
                        if (!formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid && ( typeof min == 'number' && amount < min || typeof max == 'number' && amount > max )) {
                                formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid = true;
                        }

                        console.log(amount, initialAmount);
                        if (formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid) {
                            //$(el).removeClass(formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid ? "ng-valid" : "ng-invalid").addClass(formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid ? "ng-valid" : "ng-invalid");
                            $(this).removeClass("ng-valid").addClass("ng-invalid");
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeClass("ng-invalid").addClass("ng-valid");
                        }

                    })
                    .on("focus", function(){
                            initialAmount = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
                            $(this).val("");
                    })
                    .on("keypress", function(){
                            $(this).removeClass("ng-invalid").addClass("ng-valid");
                            formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid = false;
                    });


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to use $apply() for your events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any thing which updates angular scope/binding out of its context, then angular doesn't know about. For updating that binding we need to run the digest cycle manually, which ultimately tells angular that binding has been changed and according it update bindings.

For manually running digest cycle you could use `$apply()`/`$timeout`/`$applyAsync` method over scope to see the effects.

Also instead of `$(this)` you could use `el` which has that element.

**Code**

```
.on("focus", function(){
  $timeout(function(){
    initialAmount = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
    el.val("");
  })
})
.on("keypress", function(){
  $timeout(function(){
     el.removeClass("ng-invalid").addClass("ng-valid");
     formCtrl[attrs.name].$invalid = false;
  })
});
```

Comment: @Donovant does it helped?

Comment: Parker: sorry mate I wan't in front the computer these two days. Yes it helped me, thanks a lot.
I used $scope.$apply() into onBlur event.

Comment: @Donovant Glad to help you.. Thanks :) bdw Its **Parkar** not **Parker**